# Meaning of the imaginary term in the Fourier transform of sin(x)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Can someone explain why there is an imaginary term when taking the fourier transform of sin(x)? I can see the math, but shouldn't the fourier transform of sin(x) be equivalent to $delta(x -1)$? I'm also not seeing how there are two deltas and especially why one of them is negative.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformSine.html

Comment: $sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(exp(ix)-exp(-ix)\right)$

Comment: @KuderaSebastian So what? that term simplifies to a real number. i*delta does not simplify into a real number...

Comment: Well, the transform is _not_ $\delta(x-1)$. It's hard to answer the question "shouldn't it be that?" - why _should_ it be that?

Comment: The Fourier transform of an odd function is purely imaginary. Do you expect all Fourier transforms to be real? Why, when you are integrating against a complex exponential function?

Comment: @Paul I did not realize the F.T. of odd function is imaginary. I don't see how that is the case

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since F.T. just decomposes a signal into its frequencies, and sin(x) has only one frequency, then the fourier transform should just be delta(x-1)

Comment: @Paul The FT of a _real-valued_ odd function is imaginary.

Comment: The statement "F.T. just decomposes a signal into its frequencies" is too vague to be either true or false. It may be a useful way to think about it, but if you try to use it in place of calculations you're in trouble - whatever you think that statement means, the truth is not that simple. (Proof that things are not that simple: That slogan is leading you to an incorrect FT for $\sin$.)

Comment: Look. Say $g(t)=f(-t)$. The using a change of variable in the _definition_ of the FT it follows that $\hat g(\xi)=\hat f(-\xi)$. Hence if $f$ is _odd_ then $\hat f$ is also odd.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm confused. I always thought that the F.T. was simply a decomposition of a function into its frequencies. Where did my interpretation go wrong such that a signal has imaginary frequencies?

Comment: So you always thought that $\sin(t)=\cos(t)$??? One more time: whatever you think "the F.T. was simply a decomposition of a function into its frequencies" means, **it is not that simple**.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, i always thought that sin(t) = sin(t). The F.T. of sin(t) should be just 1 because 1 is the only frequency.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I just realized, that multiplication of imaginary number is merely a phase shift. You could've just said that to me and I would've been much more satisfied than your "it is not that simple"

Comment: But $1$ is also the only frequency for $\cos(t)$, so the FT of $\cos(t)$ should also be just $1$.

Comment: I could have just said that? The transform of $\sin(t)$ is $1/(2i)(\delta(\xi-1)-\delta(\xi+1))$. The coefficient is _not_ a phase shift. Regardless, complaining about the quality of the explanation here is not a good idea - where you've been going wrong is that nothing you've said has actually been mathematically correct. When you're making no sense at all you shouldn't expect people to hit the nail on the head to your satisfactiion.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Of course I'm not making mathematical sense because i'm talking entirely about intuition. You're not understanding my question since I'm not asking about math. I need some connection between my intuition and the math done

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich All I want to know is, the F.T. of sin(t) takes it into the frequency domain. sin(t) is made up of only one real valued frequency, so why is it imaginary in the frequency domain? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Also, I'm pretty sure the imaginary value is simply a phase shift: "The Fourier transform of a function of time is... whose complex argument is the phase offset of the basic sinusoid in that frequency."

Comment: Where the $i$ comes from was explained in the very first comment - the one you dismissed with "so what". Regarding that quote, "argument" does not mean "coefficient".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Not sure what you're getting at. That comment I dismissed is completely irrelevant to my question. The $i$ most definitely indicates a phase change to the corresponding frequency $\omega = 1$ and I think that the division of 2 indicates the split energy between the frequencies.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, that first comment may have some relevance, in that if you already understood that $i$ was a phase change, you could understand that my $i$ is also a phase change but if that was his/her point, an explanation would've been preferred.

Comment: Goldname, the sinewave $\sin t$ has two real frequencies: $\omega= +1$ and $\omega=-1$. The FT catches both of those. The same applies to cosine. You need them both to write all the waves of the form $A\sin t+B\cos t$. Two degrees of freedom, $A$ and $B$, $\implies$ you need two coefficients in the frequency domain as well. Those will be the coefficients of $\delta(x-1)$ and $\delta(x+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imaginary term indicates a phase shift.

It is a constant that can be taken out of the inverse fourier transform, which would give back a cosine, and then phase shift would be applied to the cosine to return a sine.